# How to get a password from the data entry field?

Tags: java, postgresql

**WebSecurityConfig** class

```
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private UserService userSevice;

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/static/**", "/about").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userSevice)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);


        }

    }
```

**UserService** class

```
    public class UserService implements UserDetailsService  {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepo userRepo;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
            System.out.println(username);

            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
            }

            return user;
        }
 }
```

`UserDetailsService` displays only the username, but I would like it so that I could still see which password will be entered, I entered `system.out.printl(username)` for verification, and it displays, And I don’t know how to output the password. They are taken from the database. Thanks in advance .Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

So, In essence, what you want is the password sent via the client from `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`'s auth object. If yes, this will not be possible as the passwords are stored in irreversible hashes. 
If you want to get the password from DB, you can call `user.getPassword()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpServletRequest request =((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
String passwordFromForm = request.getParameter("password");
```